# Apportable Errors With iOS app conversion

Tags: android, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, apportable, spritebuilder

I am running the command "apportable load" in the directory of my x-code project for an app that is working on the iOS simulator. I have x-code 5.0.2 and when I try to update apportable it says it is the newest version.

I am sorry for the extent of the error output as it may be difficult to read. I notice some errors that are picking out the sound effects and that they cannot be referenced.

Why are the references to settings such as CCScreenModeFixed not identified when they come directly from the spritebuilder interface? Does apportable support sound effects, if so why can't it find mine?

> /Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m:58: error: undefined
>   reference to 'CCSetupScreenMode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m:58: error: undefined
>   reference to 'CCScreenModeFixed'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(AppDelegate.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_22: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCBReader'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(AppDelegate.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m:function
>   OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppController: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCAppDelegate'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(AppDelegate.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/AppDelegate.m:function
>   OBJC_CLASS_$_AppController: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCAppDelegate' /Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:186: error: undefined
>   reference to 'clampf'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_OALSimpleAudio'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_73: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCBReader'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_122: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCDirector'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_133: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCActionMoveBy'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_138: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCActionSequence'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_141: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCActionEaseBounce'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   OBJC_METACLASS_$_Gameplay: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Gameplay.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Gameplay.m:function
>   OBJC_CLASS_$_Gameplay: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Goal.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Goal.m:function
>   OBJC_METACLASS_$_Goal: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Goal.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Goal.m:function OBJC_CLASS_$_Goal:
>   error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Hiss.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Hiss.m:function
>   OBJC_METACLASS_$_Hiss: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(Hiss.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/Hiss.m:function OBJC_CLASS_$_Hiss:
>   error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(MainScene.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/MainScene.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCBReader'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(MainScene.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/MainScene.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_1: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCDirector'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(MainScene.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/MainScene.m:function
>   L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_6: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_OALSimpleAudio'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(MainScene.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/MainScene.m:function
>   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainScene: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCNode'
>
> /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.apportable.Eltie/Eltie/libEltie.a(MainScene.m.o):/Users/mateusz/Documents/SpriteBuilder
>   Games/Eltie.spritebuilder/Source/MainScene.m:function
>   OBJC_CLASS_$_MainScene: error: undefined reference to
>   'OBJC_CLASS_$_CCNode' ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. Error:
>   command failed:
>   /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/ninja/ninja
>   --no-strip-ansi-escapes -j 8 /Users/mateusz/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/Eltie/Eltie-debug.apk

Comment: Looks like cocos2d is not being linked. Does it link for iOS?

Comment: Yeah, I run my game on multiple simulators within x-code without any problems.

Comment: Does your app build cocos2d or use a pre-build .a file?

Comment: I do a clean build and I see that it compiles all the cocos2d files.

Comment: however in build phases,link binary with libraries, libcocos2d.a exists and it is highlighted red.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out with the help of the answer from this question: [static libs with apportable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554844/how-to-link-a-fat-static-libs-with-apportable)

I did not have the cocos2d library added in the target dependencies section of the build phases tab in x-code. When I added it apportable had no issues finding the undefined types given from spritebuilder and cocos2d.